# How many different arrangements among four random digits there occur 2 or 1 repetition.

Tags: combinatorics

How many different arrangements among four random digits there occur 2 or 1 repetition? 
This is part from an exercise in Feller VI, pag 53. (second edition)

Comment: Decimal digits?

Comment: yes, digits goes from 0..9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We count (i) the number of $4$-digit sequences that are "four of a kind," like $5555$; (ii) The number that are three of a kind, like $1115$ and $1611$; (iii) the number that are have two pairs, like $1414$ or $4411$; (iv) the number with $1$ pair.

(i) This is easy, there are $10$ such strings.

(ii) The digit we have $3$ of can be chosen in $10$ ways. For each way, the accompanying singleton can be chosen in $9$ ways. And for every way of doing this, we have $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to choose the location of the singleton, for a total of $(10)(9)\binom{4}{1}$.

(iii) We count the number of two pair hands. The digits we have two each of can be chosen in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways. For each such way, the **locations** of the higher ranking digits can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{10}{2}\binom{4}{2}$.

(iv) Finally, we count the one pair pair hands. The digit used in the pair can be chosen in $10$ ways. **Where** it occurs in the string can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. And then the remaining slots can be filled in $(9)(8)$ ways, for a total of $(10)\binom{4}{2}(9)(8)$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point, but with no repetition we get 10.9.8.7, right? The complement for that is one or more repetitions. I need exactly one repetition (like 2445,4667,2339,etc) and two repetition (2223,5554,6466,etc)

Comment: Let's clarify what you want to count. Call a number **good** if it has a $2$ or $1$ repetition. Is $2225$ good? is $1011$ good? Is $2777$ good?

Comment: Sorry André, I didnt make myself clear. I want to do 2 different counts. The first one: 4 digits numbers with 2 repetitions ( numbers like 3334, 1666, 7077, 9979). The second one: 4 digits numbers with 1 repetition (3221,0304,6876,etc).

Comment: Yes, I had misunderstood, thought the question was harder, involved special treatment of the digit $2$. All questions about pairs, triples, quadruples are answered.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope the logical structure of the counting is clear.

Comment: Pretty clear! :D